# Angular6 @ViewChildren using identifier

Tags: angular

I have created a directive with a selected **pyb-button-group** that uses `@ViewChildren`, which is declared like this:

```
@ViewChildren('header', { read: ElementRef }) headers: QueryList<ElementRef>
```

My html template looks a bit like this:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="categories">
  <div class="row" pyb-button-group>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-6" *ngFor="let category of categories">
      <a class="btn-choice" [routerLink]="['/' + category.id]">
        <div class="header" #header>
          <span class="title">{{ category.name }}</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have a method that fires using `ngAfterViewInit` like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.headers);
}
```

and it returns `undefined`....

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What about categories? Is this async data? If yes it is possible the template is not fully created when ngAfterViewInit() fires

Comment: let me update my template :D there is another div around the directive

Comment: doesn't should be ```@ContentChildren('header', { read: ElementRef }) headers: QueryList<ElementRef>``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be something like:

```
@ContentChildren('header', { read: ElementRef }) headers: QueryList<ElementRef>

ngAfterViewInit(){
 this.headers.toArray().forEach(el => {
      console.log(el);
  });
 }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-ksqunn)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ngAfterContentInit` instead of  `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: what is the purpose of `.toArray()`? I didn't use that method and it still worked?

Comment: @r3plica i just added to get the result, it's OK to not use.

Comment: @callOfCode elements which are used between the opening and closing tags of the host element of a given component are called content children and it's not about initializing view or content.

Answer (score 0):

It will work with ViewChildern also,

```
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChildren('header', { read: ElementRef }) headers: QueryList<ElementRef>
  categories: {
    name: string
  }[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = [];
    this.categories.push({ name: "Test" }, { name: "Test2" });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.headers);
    this.headers.toArray().forEach(header => console.log(header));
  }
}
```

Here is a working sample,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdkdro

Comment: where is your directive?